# How to delete a DNS record in Route53 via aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I am using aws cli to create and delete DNS record in Route 53. I am not sure about the payload or the command that has to be used. As per [this link](https://gist.github.com/earljon/8579429f90c3480c06eb2bc952255987), I created this payload, but it's not working. The payload is

```
{
"Comment": "Delete single record set",
"Changes": [
    {
        "Action": "DELETE",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "$DNS_NAME.",
            "Type": "$RECORD_TYPE",
            "TTL": $TTL,
            "ResourceRecords": [
                {
                    "Value": "${RESOURCE_VALUE}"
                }
            ]                
        }
    }
]
```

}

which I handled in a variable called payload
And the AWS cli command is

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ${HOSTED_ZONE_ID} --change-batch payload
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Can anyone please confirm if the command and the payload is correct?

Comment: Did you try it? What do you mean by "not working"? Did you get an error message? Did you substitute for `$DNS_Name`, `$RECORD_TYPE`, `$TTL`, `${RESOURCE_VALUE}` and `${HOSTED_ZONE_ID}`? Can you give us an idea of what type of record it was?

Comment: How do you specify `--change-batch payload`? Is payload a file or a string in bash?

Comment: @Marcin payload is a variable which is basically the payload that I created above. Can't we send it this way? Or do we have to send it through a file

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes I substituted the values and it was record type 'A'.  It was giving InvalidChangeBatch error.

Comment: The example you linked is using `file://` which would be better. If its variable you probably have issues with quotes, spaces etc. Reading from file would be worth trying.

Answer (score 7):

Save the payload into a json file and Input the filename. Use file:// protocol to refer the payload path.

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZSDAGFDG35GS --change-batch file://tmp/payload.json
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to delete the DNS ResourceRecords name with the command and the json inline:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id XXXXXXXXYYY --change-batch "{\"Changes\": [{\"Action\": \"DELETE\",\"ResourceRecordSet\": {\"Name\": \"app.my-test.com.\",\"Type\": \"A\",\"AliasTarget\": {\"HostedZoneId\": \"xxxxyyyyzzzwww\",\"DNSName\": \"my-test-elb-xxxxxx.region.elb.amazonaws.com.\",\"EvaluateTargetHealth\": true}}}]}"
```

Comment: The question was properly answered by deepanmurugan in 2020 and your answer is not improving anything.

Comment: This mechanism is easier to use in code without having to write a file

Answer (score 1):

I have a template `playload.json.tmpl` that uses change the values

```
cat playload.json.tmpl 
{
    "Comment": "some comment here",
    "Changes": [
        {
            "Action": "TEMPLATE_ACTION",
            "ResourceRecordSet": {
                "Name": "TEMPLATE_CName_Name",
                "Type": "CNAME",
                "TTL": 300,
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "TEMPLATE_CName_Value"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I can use `sed` command to replace the `values` for the `playload.json.tmpl`
Note: The delete record set use `DELETE` action

```
sed \
-e "s%TEMPLATE_ACTION%DELETE%g" \
-e "s%TEMPLATE_CName_Name%$(echo $CName_Name)%g" \
-e "s%TEMPLATE_CName_Value%$(echo $CName_Value)%g" \
./playload.json.tmpl > ./playload.json
```

Then you can use AWS CLI to delete the record set if your file has `DELETE` action

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $DefaultHostedZoneId --change-batch file://playload.json
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to delete standard address records (not aliases), but I have multiple addresses per record.

This bash script solved the problem for me and is offered here in the hopes that it will help other people:

```bash
zid=MYZONEID

function listrrs() {
  aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $zid
}

function changerr() {
  aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $zid --change-batch "$1"
}

listrrs | jq -r '                
    .ResourceRecordSets[]|select(.Type!="NS")|select(.Type!="SOA")|
    "\(.Name) \(.Type) \(.TTL) \([.ResourceRecords[]|.Value]|join(","))"' | \
    while read name type ttl addr
  do
  echo Removing $name
  changerr '{
    "Changes":[
      {"Action":"DELETE","ResourceRecordSet":{
        "Name":"'"$name"'",
        "Type":"'"$type"'",
        "TTL":'"$ttl"',
        "ResourceRecords":[
          '"$(
               IFS=, read -a l<<<"$addr"
               for v in "${l[@]}"
               do echo -n '{"Value":"'$v'"},'
               done | sed 's/,$//'
          )"'
        ]}}
      ]
    }'
done
```

The important thing to note - if you have multiple resource records for the same name - you have to send one delete command to delete all of them.

If you want to only delete one resource record - you need to do an UPSERT command with a new set that contains all of the records to retain. Its quite annoying - you'd expect API developers to build better APIs, but this is a Route53 problem and the AWS CLI developers could have exposed a nicer API on top of that, but they chose to offer just plain Route53 JSON requests - with all their complexity - making the Route53 CLI the most painful CLI in all of AWS (and that is saying a lot).